# fabricjs set boundingrect to the new object after cropping object using clipto method

Tags: fabricjs

I have clipped an image using clipto method of fabricjs and this works fine. But the problem is boudingrect is still to the actual image area. Is there any way to reset boundingrect same as new cropped image? I tried setCoords but this does not work.

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FabricJS has two methods available to "crop" an object, the one you are using [clipTo()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clipTo), and a [toDataURL()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toDataURL) method.  Using `toDataURL()` creates a new image with a reset boundingrect same as new cropped image.

```js
fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAACa0lEQVRYhbVXMW7bQBAcMgRTWCJdC+qFOLAaudFDnEKdYL1AfoCRB8gvkJJUAQw/RI3cSIBg13ZShzxWBEK6sEjf7e3dkYC8Fckhduf2doZHryzLEpY4e/mp3M+jEW7TB/bdq+457rMnpGVeP9v3p7b08K0oE7NoiHk0Yotfxxdt07UnsEy3Gomq+F32qKy+SQRtCVTtn0VDAEBS5nXx7//WbdPpBOQ9/3YywDwaYRYNsUy3dfHksMquHwLF27uieF+53JFFssFK7Gps3Zsg9j+bCcjFb07H+PrnFwD3ik14NYQyCWsH5OKe5wHQ206Lu/BqODkSGgFanBbp+iG71y7cpBDvy/MPxQeozmUdL9Nt3WIuOFyeKc4ntA5UbaRmIw8htyIXXg3mffakPNd8gNM5Tb4SOyySTWPc5hNaB+hA0eRyEQCIvdCKy8W52fDn0Qj7/lRZsazzxOJsosideOyF9XUVV91z7PtT3JyOEbiczaRjqhYT7vKRAGivY1rchdvy1zPQVMeiyFmfcOGm/MoQJmVeezsXsRcCPrTkTXEuf02Afs8/ygdo/kAG77JHiCLXzIjTuVzEhdvyByadfrQPVPmDldhpEpJ94OV/piWvQhS59Uwlihz9T533dw9xmz6oWyAHZXxsH6Dd0ghw7TqmDyzFzv41NHn2sXyAhkf/CxbJxvo9Nw2dCafnicvOwH4mpBKSk9t8oqmPXHYGynP2TNhGx01wk5SNBGQSLh27Tsm24iyBdW+i3I///rb6BPdfIOt83ZsobY8O5wMjAXlAuHB1hK7Wla/1rxlX3KZzV7QmYPIJ2z7b4hVhK2M6UYICmwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', function(origImage) {
  var origBoundingRect = origImage.getBoundingRect();
  fabric.Image.fromURL(origImage.toDataURL({
    width: origImage.width - 5,
    height: origImage.height - 5
  }), function(newImage) {
    var newBoundingRect = newImage.getBoundingRect();
    console.log('origBoundingRect:\r\n' + JSON.stringify(origBoundingRect) + '\r\n\r\n' + 'newBoundingRect:\r\n' + JSON.stringify(newBoundingRect));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

If you run the code snip-it above it logs to the console a before and after shot of the boundingrect.

Hope this helps, matey.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Sorry I was away for last two weeks. This is what actually I was looking for. It works perfectly for me with miner changes! Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Glad it helped.  If you don't mind marking it as the "accepted" answer by clicking on the tick it'd help others searching for something similar.